# IIS + PHP - Url Rewrite Issue

Tags: php, iis, url-rewriting

first of all my english is not so good and thats because i cant found what i found.

Ok, here is my web.config rules

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1">
                <match url="^Girisyap$" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="giris.php" />
            </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">>
                  <match url="^([0-9a-zA-Z-_/]+)$" />
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="Sayfalar.php?Sayfa={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

With this rules, when i try to visit **http:// localhost:84/Girisyap** it showing giris.php as well.
If i visit **http:// localhost:84/Around** showing me Sayfalar.php?Sayfa=Around as well to.
But when i visit **http:// localhost:84/** it giving me 403.14 - Forbidden error. Because im not using index.php or default.php and i dont want it.

How can show **'Sayfalar.php?Sayfa='** *(Sayfa is empty)* visiting to **http:// localhost:84/** as well

Answer (score 0):

In Apache you will find an index.php file in htdocs that will set the default website to xampp folder(by default). Maybe you must find the same case in IIS. Try to edit the default website to your website's directory and maybe you can set you binding to other port(as you want and it is enable to use=84). Good luck, it's working to me.
Add this code to web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
     <defaultDocument>
        <files>
          <add value="Login.aspx" />
        </files>
     </defaultDocument>
     <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

Note : Login.aspx is an example. Change it to your default document.

Comment: Im not having website directory issue. Im just tryig to not getting 403 error. Instead of this, i want to show 'Sayfalar.php?Sayfa='. Is there any way to do that in web.config file.

Comment: That was directory listing issue. It was denied by something or maybe the confirguration. If you're looking for error in web.config file try to add the code                           <system.webServer>
     <defaultDocument>
        <files>
          <add value="Login.aspx" />
        </files>
     </defaultDocument>
     <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>